# Is $Z$ a subspace of $L(V,W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Let $Z$ be the subset of $L(V,W)$ consisting of those linear maps $f$ for which there exists a $v ∈ V$ with $f(v) = w_0$. Where $w_0$ is fixed and nonzero.

I find it somehow difficult to find a counterexample to disprove the statement. But I cannot prove it yet by finding a vector $v$ that satisfies $(f+g)(v)=w_0$ .

Could someone give an counterexample or prove it? Many thanks!

Comment: Is $w_0$ a fixed element?

Comment: Yes. And it is non zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w_0\neq 0$. Now take $f\in Z$.  Then $g:=-f\in Z$ (by linearity) but $f+g\equiv 0\notin Z$.

---

EDIT: Actually even easier: $w_0\neq 0$. Then the $0$ map is not contained in $Z$, so it cannot be a linear subspace.

---

For $w_0=0$ just take non invertible matrices whose sum is an invertible matrix, for example 
$$f:=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix},\quad g:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: It seems that when $w_0=0, Z$ would be equal to $L(V,W)$. The reason is when $w_0=0$, then for any $f \in L(V,W)$, we always have $0 \in V$ s.t. $f(0)=0=w_0.$